# When openning netrw in split view, the opened buffer I'm still editing clears when I click a line number

Tags: netrw

Wondering why this happens, if it is a bug or supposed to happen?

Steps to reproduce:

1. open vim,
2. split two windows, one with netrw and another with few lines of text (line numbers enabled).
3. As both of them are open, click any number on the line numbers column, the buffer will clear.

The interesting part is, this doesn't happen on NeoVim.

Comment: Hi mike, welcome to [vi.se]! You’re question is a little unclear. Can you describe exactly the behavior youre seeing and the actions youre taking? This will help you get better answers. If you can also provide the smallest possible vimrc that displays this behavior, that will be helpful. You can use the [edit] button to add this information to your question

Comment: @D.BenKnoble hello hope I clarified in the update, I'm not able to find a solution by using a search engine.

Comment: mike, thanks. You're new information was enough for me to track down the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to reproduce this, and here's what's happening.

#### Setup

1. Open vim
2. Type a few lines of text
3. `:Sexplore`
4. With the focus on netrw, click on the buffer with text (esp. on the line numbers).

That buffer switches to a new buffer (generally named after the line you clicked on).

### Why?

`netrw` maps `<LeftMouse>` to call the scriptlocal function `NetrwLeftmouse(1)`. This function is responsible for editing the files you click on. It tries to abort if you don't click in the window (`if ... || v:mouse_win != winnr()`), but I believe by the time this executes the mouse window and `winnr()` have been aligned (the mapping actually performs a regular `<LeftMouse>` first, so focus has already changed).

The function happily carries on and edits a new buffer. `<C-o>` is sometimes enough to get you back, but because the function uses `NetrwKeepj`, the jumplist doesn't change, so `<C-o>` may not suffice.

### Solutions

1. Don't use the mouse in netrw (easy to give up, but might accidentally still get you). Combine with unmapping the mouse keys in `netrw` (in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim` for example) for maximum effect.
2. ??? This would require a serious patch for a strange edge case, and I'm not quite sure how to do it yet.

Comment: @mike remember to accept the answer (with the green check mark under the voting buttons) if you are happy with it. This will help future reader with the same issue to find this information more easily.